# running on CheckedListBox and check what in the file

Tags: c#, winforms

i have CheckedListBox  that contain:

```
AA
BB
CC
DD
```

i have string that contain: `CC`

i need that in the CheckedListBox  will be checked `CC`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it after the items have been added, there is an example [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.objectcollection.aspx)

```
private void CheckEveryOther_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    // Cycle through every item and check every other.

    // Set flag to true to know when this code is being executed. Used in the ItemCheck
    // event handler.
    insideCheckEveryOther = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++) {

          // here you need to compare with that string....
                checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Indeterminate);
            else
                checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
        }
    }        

    insideCheckEveryOther = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the checkListBox.Items, and for each item, search the item in the string, using myStr.Contains(item.ToString()) and mark the item as selected or not, based on the contains result.

```
        string myStr = "CC";
        for (int it = 0; it < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; it++)
        {
            checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(
               it, myStr.Contains(checkedListBox1.Items[it].ToString()));
        }
```